# Find a Element by attribute in a XML Document in Java and get value of another attribute in the same element

Tags: java, python, xml, lxml

I was tasked to convert some of my Python code to Java.

In the original there is a lot of operations like this:

```
name = element.find('*/DIAttribute[@name="ui_display_name"]').attrib['value']
```

Where element is a `lxml.etree.Element` object.

In Java I'm doing this to get the same value:

```
XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList nodesName = (NodeList) xPath.evalute("DIAttribute[@name='ui_display_name']", element, XPathConstants.NODE);
if nodesName.getLength() > 0 {
    Node node = nodesName.item(0);
    name = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("value");
}
```

I'm doing it right? There is a better way of doing this? I'm using the `org.w3c.dom` objects, and the powers that be forbid me of using other XML libraries.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you having a specific problem?  Is your code working?  Is the DIAttribute you’re trying to find an immediate child of `element`?

Comment: @VGR, it works, but it looks so more complex than the python code that I can not shake the feeling that I'm doing it in the worst way possible. An no, it is not always the immediate child of element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing XPathConstants.NODE does not cause `evaluate` to return a NodeList, it causes the method to return a single Node.  The [class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants.html) describes exactly what type of object will be returned for each XPathConstant field.

```
Node node = (Node) xPath.evaluate("DIAttribute[@name='ui_display_name']", element, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Attributes are document nodes too, so you can simplify the code into a single XPath expression:

```
Node node = (Node) xPath.evaluate("DIAttribute[@name='ui_display_name']/@value", element, XPathConstants.NODE);
String name = node.getNodeValue();
```

Since you just want the string value of the node, you can use the [two-argument evaluate method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#evaluate-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) instead, omitting the XPathConstants value:

```
String name = xPath.evaluate("DIAttribute[@name='ui_display_name']/@value", element);
```

That will only find DIAttribute elements which are direct children of `element`.  If you want to search all DIAttribute descendants at all levels below `element`, use `.//` in your XPath expression:

```
String name = xPath.evaluate(".//DIAttribute[@name='ui_display_name']/@value", element);
```

Comment: Thank you @VGR ! I knew I was doing something very wrong! That code was too ugly to be correct.